# Regex how to move all matched char to the end of string

Tags: regex, replace

I want to move all matched characters(in this case f, z, x, r, and s) in a string to the end of it.

For example:

```
chafo -> chaof

sasc -> sacs

chafof -> chaoff
```

I tried a replacement regex:

```
Pattern: "/(.+)([f|z|x|r|s])+(.*)/"

Replacement: "$1$3$2"
```

But it just makes: `chafo -> chaof`, and not `chafof -> chaoff`

Can anyone help me out?

**Update:**

One more thing, is there a way to change: `truwowfng -> truwowngf`

By this I mean, if `r` goes after `t` or is the second character, it won't be moved.

Thanks again!

Comment: in a character class eg. `[f|z|x|r|s]` the pipe `|` doesn't mean `OR`, it's just the pipe character, meaning it will accept a pipe in a word like `cha|cha`. therefore your character class should only be `[fzxrs]` (no pipes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need a no-gready quantifier such as `/(.+?)([fzxrs]+)(.*)/`, or specifying which characters you don't want to move: `/(.[^fzxrs]*)([fzxrs]+)(.*)/`.

This will move the first occurance (except if in first possition) of any wanted character to the end.  Your code will move the last one to the end.  Tha's why *chafof* fails: it moves the last *f* to the end.

Comment: Great! that works! I'm a noob btw :D

One more thing, is there a way to change: `truwowfng -> truwowngf`?
I mean, if **r** goes after **t** or is the second character, it won't be moved.
Could you help me please :D

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @CasperPas Can you please add this new requirement to question?

Answer (score 2):

Try following **regex**

```
s/(.+?)([fzxs]|(?<!t|^.)r)(.*)/$1$3$2/g
```

**Short Description**

`(.+?)` will make `+` lazy as desired

`(?<!t|^.)r)` will skip matching `r` which is preceded by `t` or is second character in a string.

Check this in action [here](http://regex101.com/r/iC1qR2)

**Input**

```
chafo
sasc
chafof
truwowfng
arbcd
abcrd
```

**Output**

```
chaof
sacs
chaoff
truwowngf
arbcd
abcdr
```

Comment: Great! it works in PHP. I tried your link to regex101 but it doesn't work with Javascript or Python. Is that because of the tool?

Comment: @CasperPas different tools may or may not support different constructs (e.g. look behind). Most of the times I have observed it's because of special characters like `[ ( ) ]` may or may not require escaping them. Above regrex also works fine with perl. You just need to play around and figure out correct syntax for other languages.